# Interior pont related curve

Tags: real-analysis

Do you believe that there is any relation between a global maximum and a local maximum?for example,is any global maximum necessarily a local maximum? or is any local maximum necessarily a global maximum?

Comment: How does the title relate to your question? It is true some books define a local min or max only for interior points, so a global max at an endpoint does not count as a local max (however bizarre this may sound)

Answer (score 1):

A global maximum is not necessarily a local maximum, and a local maximum may not be a global maximum.

max{local maxs}=global max if the function $\in \mathcal{C}^0$

Comment: A global maximum is necessarily a local maximum.

Comment: @Juanito For the commonly accepted definitions, a global maximum is not necessarily a local maximum. Consider f(x)=1 when x>2 and f(0)=2 and f(x) is undefined elsewhere

Comment: I can see where the disagreement might arise. But for most purposes, it is not impossible to define neighborhoods. For example, in your example, it can be defined as the intersection of the domain with a standard epsilon ball. Once neighborhoods have been defined, local maxima are defined. In your example, at x=0 we would have a local maximum trivially.

Comment: At least in first year calculus, terminal points are not considered local maximum. It is ok to define something else, though.

Comment: I am guessing that has more to do with equating local optima with derivatives.

Comment: I think so..... :)

Answer (score 0):

A global maximum is necessarily a local maximum as well. But a local maximum may not be a global maximum.

Comment: What is the key point of this problem??